# Javascript Time Difference Calculation

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I have this function

```
function timeCalculator(form)
{
    var currentTimeAndDate = new Date();
    var userTimeAndDate = form.userDate.value;
    var userUTCOffset2 = form.userUTCOffset.value;
    var userDate = new Date(userTimeAndDate);
    var tzDifference = currentTimeAndDate.getTimezoneOffset() + (userUTCOffset2 - currentTimeAndDate.getTimezoneOffset());
    var timeDifference = new Date((userDate.getTime()+(tzDifference*60*1000))-(currentTimeAndDate.getTime()+(userDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)));

    var hours = Math.floor(timeDifference.getTime() / 36e5),
    minutes = Math.floor(timeDifference.getTime() % 36e5 / 60000),
    seconds = Math.floor(timeDifference.getTime() % 60000 / 1000);

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "There is exactly "+hours+" hours,"+minutes+"minutes and "+seconds+" seconds left until your specified time.";
}
```

What this is supposed to do is a user inputs a time, date and UTC offset in a form and based on that it calculates how much time is left until that point. The minutes and seconds seem to work fine, but there is a problem with the hours. Anyone have any suggestions or maybe a different approach to something like this? Also how can I add days, months, years in the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for this.  It will save you a lot of grief.

```
function timeCalculator(form)
{
    // get a moment based on the user input
    var m = moment(form.userDate.value).zone(form.userUTCOffset.value);

    // calculate a duration of time passed between now and that moment
    var now = moment();
    var d = moment.duration(m - now);

    // build your output string
    var s = d.hours() + " hours, " +
            d.minutes() + " minutes, and " +
            d.seconds() + " seconds";

    // set the output html
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "There are exactly " + s +
                                          " left until your specified time.";
}
```

This assumes a future date chosen, and that you always want hours, minutes, and seconds shown.

You might instead consider a more generalized approach, which shows an *approximation* of the time due or remaining:

```
function timeCalculator(form)
{
    // get a moment based on the user input
    var m = moment(form.userDate.value).zone(form.userUTCOffset.value);

    // get a humanized duration string
    var s = m.fromNow(true);

    // set the output html
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "There are " + s +
                                          " left until your specified time.";
}
```

See the documentation on [`fromNow`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) for details about the expected output.

As an aside, it seems a bit weird to pass in the form and the set the result in a hardcoded element.  You might want to just pass in the form values and return the string result, letting the caller of your function handle where they come from and go to.

Comment: thank you for pointing out moment.js to save us from the agony.